# Difference between memory_limit and php_memory_limit

Tags: php, php.ini

In my `php.ini` file I can see settings for both

```
memory_limit
```

and

```
php_memory_limit
```

What is the difference between these two settings?

(Both settings are set to 512Mb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php_memory_limit` is not a [PHP ini configuration setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

`memory_limit` is the [correct setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).  The other is being ignored.